# connecting to sql server without IP address and host name on the internet

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-ip

I don't know ip address and host name of a system on internet.I only know database name, how do i connect with that database using internet and without using any third part tool.

Comment: How do you send snail-mail to a person, if you only know the persons name and not his/her address?

Comment: If the problem is that you have a dynamic ip, then you either have to use a 3rd party tool, or write one yourself. You need to store the ip address of the server somewhere where you can fetch it.

Answer (score 3):

Basically... you can't.

Every Database-Server can provide databases with any name, so you can have Database `foo` on server `x` and at the same time on server `y` with different data.

So without any additional info you can't get the adress of the server.

---

**Edit:**
**Q:** Actually server does not have static IP it generates dynamic IP.
**A:** You can use a [**DDNS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) prvider, to create a hostname, which changes automatically the IP adress depending on your current server IP, but without a 3rd party app it seems difficult.

Comment: Actually server does not have static IP it generates dynamic IP.

Comment: I don't have to use any third party tool.